# "Unexpected" quotation marks: Why?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, signage

I frequently run into uses of quotation marks on public display that simply baffle me. I have no idea who or what is being quoted, what the original reference is, or why it's necessary to indicate that this is a quote.

[image: Quotation marks around sign message "road work ahead".]

Clearly it's no accident: **the quotation marks take effort to add**. Someone had to go to the trouble of putting them there, someone who felt he had a reason to do so.

If it were a one-off occurrence, I would chalk it up to miscommunication. But this is so common a practice that I wonder if there's some common misconception, or perhaps convention in a foreign language which leads people to place quotation marks where they are not, in English, traditionally expected.

Alternately, is there some meaning communicated here that I am missing? Do these quotation marks actually indicate something of which I wasn't aware?

Comment: Quotes for emphasis are fairly common. It's a native thing.

Comment: @Gilles What makes you say that? I really don’t think so.

Comment: It's even mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Nonstandard_usage). @tchrist Note that I don't claim that it's *correct*.

Comment: @Gilles native to where? It certainly isn't in the US.

Comment: This is just another fine candidate for [The “blog” of “unnecessary” quotation marks](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/).

Comment: If the sign read ' "Minefield" ', one could argue they were scare quotes.

Comment: @tylerl (and tchrist): It's totally common in the U.S. I see it all the time.

Comment: @tylerl [it is native in the US alright](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/6263/300). Your very own post suggests that it is, does it not. If you ask me, it is native everywhere. It is native in other languages, for that matter. Not *all* languages, mind you (from my personal and anecdotal experience), but a great many languages. People just don't know how to use quotation marks. Most people don't know how to use X whatever X is.

Comment: Perhaps it's meant to be ironic. The "road" may be a dirt path. Maybe the "workers" are all dozing on the job. The "ahead" may be 10 miles off. Or Perhaps all three.

Comment: Most of these comments are concerned with bemoaning the "ungrammaticality" of the sign. But it's at least *possible* the signwriter was deliberately taking advantage of the fact that people naturally ***pay more attention*** to words in quotes, since this often means the words don't have their ordinary meaning. Anything that makes people pay more attention to such signs is probably a good idea, regardless of the lack of grammatical justification.

Comment: The triangular road sign with the bare exclamation mark is far more ungrammatical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That’s because your ⚠ is missing its surrounding quotation marks.

Comment: Also see   [When is it appropriate to use “scare quotes”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69547) and  (less relevantly)  [Is the use of the quotation marks necessary with expressions like “self-proclaimed”, “self-styled”, “so-called” and “would be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/117651)

Comment: From "Weird Al" Yankovic's "Word Crimes" [I hope you never use "quotation marks" for "emphasis"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc&feature=youtu.be&t=2m32s)

Answer (score 11):

There are plenty of times that quotation marks can change the meaning of a short piece of text, however, I don't think that's the case here.

It's quite likely that this was indeed the result of a miss-communication, but not the kind you're thinking of. If you were received a written message telling you to place the words *"road work ahead"* on the sign, it might not immediately occur to you that the quotes were not intended to be part of the message.

This kind of thing is not that uncommon. Here's a more obvious example of what I mean:
[image: Cake is decorated with writing: "Way to finish strong, Bull Dogs", followed by the words "All Caps" in patentheses.]

Here, the intent was obviously to indicate that the message written on the cake should be with uppercase letters, but the baker mistook "*(All Caps)*" as part of the message itself.

Comment: Actually I doubt this is a mistake. The baker did **exactly** what he was told to do. It's not the responsibility of contractors to proof-read or interpret what they are told.

Answer (score 7):

You're not missing anything.  There has recently been an unfortunate trend to use quotation marks where they're not warranted or appropriate. You can see many more examples of this in at [the blog](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/) tchrist linked [in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124494/unexpected-quotation-marks-why#comment256497_124494).

Quotation marks should not be used for emphasis or no reason at all, as in your example and most in the aforementioned blog.

Comment: I don't buy *the only permissible use for quotation marks is quotation*. I've no problem with saying it's "permissible" to use them when you're using a word "loosely" - for example, where the intended meaning isn't necessarily *exactly* what the reader might have otherwise expected. Thus, in my own usage here, I'm using the quote marks to indicate that *my* definition of the word "permissible" isn't the same as yours (I'm specifically *not* using them simply to indicate that I'm "quoting" the word you used).

Comment: That was the meaning I was trying to encompass with "if only what a theoretical person may say." A "straw-man quote," one might say.

Comment: I'm not convinced *any* "authority" would adopt such a narrow definition. Here's a typical page I just found... [Aside from conveying that a character in a text is speaking, quotation marks have other uses. One is to set off the title of a book or movie. Another is **to denote irony or that the speech is not to be taken at the obvious value** the words would seem to mean.](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/practice-using-quotation-marks.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fine, you win.

Comment: Downvote reversed. (Sorry if I came across as a bit of a "bulldozer" there! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No worries FumbleFingers, you are "forgiven".

Answer (score 2):

While I find this practice (i.e., the mistaken use of quotation marks for emphasis) utterly deplorable in formal writing and hand-written signs, it might be somewhat excusable in electronic road signs, when more appropriate means of emphasis (e.g., italics, boldface, underline, etc.) are unavailable.

In CS (Sorry. That's jargon for "Computer Science!"), rendering a message, or even an ENTIRE sentence, in upper-case is considered gauche (The CS term is "shouting"); however, I believe its use for a SINGLE word or SHORT phrase is a reasonable substitute for the otherwise-unavailable tools of emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

When using signs where the message may not always fit (think scrolling or flashing displays), it's a fairly common practice in CS (Computer Science) to use quotation marks to display the start and end of a message.

Comment: That might apply to the electronic road sign, but it is also very common in hand-written signs by, say, greengrocers! And it is "also" used with just a single word within a sentence on a sign. So I don't think the general trend has to do with computers?